# Mongodb is not recognising the past data files (.wt) after reinstallation

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Unfortunately, my MongoDB server crashed because of an unexpected shutdown of the server. Afterward, I have updated the MongoDB to version 3.6. Now while I am trying to restore the past databases with the new installation, the server is not recognizing the old `.wt` files.

The `.wt` files are in a different folder (`/**/**/**/**/mongod-data/`) than the usual MongoDB datapath i.e, `/var/lib/mongodb`. The permissions for the folders are set to to the usual (`drwxr-xr-x 6 mongodb mongodb 45056 Sep 16 17:18 /**/**/**/**/mongod-data/`) and I have edited the `/etc/mongodb.conf` files accordingly.

The `/**/**/**/**/mongod-data/` folder contains 22GB data (in `.wt` files) `$du -sh >> 22GB`.

The server is running with no error messages in `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`. However, while checking from the mongo shell I am seeing only the following databases but not the usual databases that I had previously:

`> show dbs: admin   0.000GB config  0.000GB local   0.000GB`

I would be thankful to you getting help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to recover/repair your existing installation, use the exact server version that you used previously, and once your installation is fixed, upgrade to the new version.

The data directory options to mongod are described in documentation.

Permissions you need to fix manually if needed, I suggest doing this as the last step.

In general you should be making one change at a time to your deployment and verifying your database works correctly after each change.

Comment: Thanks for the help @D.SM, I had followed step by step. The files were created with v 3.6. I moved a few steps back and checked the error with the previous wiredTiger files before creating new wiredTiger files, the errors were:

Comment: >> WiredTiger error (13) : __posix_open_file, 715: /*/*/*/*/mongod-data//journal/WiredTigerLog.0000000414: handle-open: open: Permission denied Raw: [1600273718:946391][17327:0x7f1bfb3cba40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /*/*/*/*/mongod-data/mongod-data//journal/WiredTigerLog.0000000414: handle-open: open: Permission denied
 Permission denied src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 488
 exception in initAndListen: Location28595: 13: Permission denied, terminating
   [initandlisten] Invariant failure globalStorageEngine src/mongo/db/service_context_d.cpp 272

Comment: After taking a backup change ownership or mode to mongod user as needed.

Comment: That didn't solve the problem. same error: Invariant failure globalStorageEngine src/mongo/db/service_context_d.cpp 272.

Comment: WiredTiger error (-31802)  file:sizeStorer.wt, WT_SESSION.open_cursor: __wt_block_read_off, 302: sizeStorer.wt: fatal read error: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error Raw:, file:sizeStorer.wt, WT_SESSION.open_cursor: __wt_block_read_off, 302: sizeStorer.wt: fatal read error: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error file:sizeStorer.wt, WT_SESSION.open_cursor: __wt_panic, 523: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic Raw: file:sizeStorer.wt, WT_SESSION.open_cursor: __wt_panic, 523: the process must exit and restart: ...

Comment: Fatal Assertion 50853 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_util.cpp ***aborting after fassert() failure [initandlisten] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).

Comment: I moved to one of the older backups and restored the dbs.